# The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe - Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have n application made in Powershell that reads result from a database and spool the data into an Excel table. When the numbers are integer i don't have any problem, but when I'm trying to spool a decimal the next error appears: "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe".

I've tried the next after the data insert:

```
$range1 = "F2:G20"
$range2 = "K2:L20"
$WorkSheet.Columns.item('F').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
$WorkSheet.Columns.item('G').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"

$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1).Copy()
$x = $WorkSheet.Range($range2).Select()
$WorkSheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(-4163,-4142)
```

But no success... There is another way? I want those 2 columns F and G to be formated as Number....

As well I've tried as well :

```
$WorkSheet.Columns.item('F').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
$WorkSheet.Columns.item('G').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
$Tr = $WorkSheet.Range('K2','L20')
$WorkSheet.Range('F2','G20').Copy()
$Tr.Select()
$Tr.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

The values are still pasting as text and not as a decimal number...

Very important : I'm trying to paste the values in a Excel Table.

Comment: The `"0.00,00"` does not seem to be a valid number mask. Which _number_ should correspond to `"1.23,45"`?

Comment: I'm working in Italy, so the decimal separator here is the , and for thousands is dot.

Comment: Despite where are you working. Which number should correspond to `"1.23,45"`? A dot isn't at thousand position…

Comment: Yes, but the thousand separator (dot) should be placed before three digits as seen from the right, not two

Comment: $WorkSheet.Columns.item('F').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
    $WorkSheet.Columns.item('G').NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"

Comment: [Excel custom number formats](https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after too much time i found a solution, better call it work arround:

1. In your Excel workbook create a table with the same name of the column of you SQL table, then insert some dummy values manually.
2. Get your data information from the DB in this way:

   $dt1 = SQLCommand -File_Path $QueryReplacedFullPath -Server "tnsdw" -Name "TMS_SalesDW" -Out
   $dt_table1 = $dt1.Tables[0]
   $WorkSheet = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $SheetName}
   $WorkSheet.Activate()
3. Delete the dummy data inserted manually before wit the next code:

   $StartRow = 2
   $FinalRow = 200
   $null = $WorkSheet.Range("A$($StartRow):A$($FinalRow)")
   $WorkSheet.usedrange.offset($StartRow,0).specialcells(12).Entirerow.Delete()
4. Insert the data in your Excel table using this command:

   for ([Int]$m = 0; $m -lt $dt_table1.Rows.Count; $m++)
   {
   for ([Int]$r = 0; $r -lt $dt_table1.Columns.Count; $r++)
   {
   $incolumn = $r + 1;
   $inrow = $inheaderlenght + 2 + $m;
   if($incolumn -gt 4)
   {
   $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($inrow, $incolumn) = [System.Convert]::ToDecimal($dt_table1.Rows[$m].ItemArray[$r])
   }
   else
   {
   $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($inrow, $incolumn) = $dt_table1.Rows[$m].ItemArray[$r].ToString()
   }
   }
   }

Note that i convert the values to decimal only in the columns that i want to be decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying formatting to the source column ranges, but not to the destination column ranges, and since you only copy the values and not the format (`.PasteSpecial -4163`) the destination format is respected where you have not specified the desired format . If you want the same formatting in the destination, you must specify it for columns K2,L20, or apply `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`